# How do I make a small help dialogue box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog

My asp.net web application is written in C#.

On many websites, I have seen small hyperlinks next to a form field that says "what's this?"

When you click it, a small help dialogue box pops up and continues to be visible so long as you hold your mouse over the link. It's usually a dialogue explaining what that part of the form is asking for.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a **tooltip plugIn**. have a look at

1. [30 stylish jQuery Tooltip plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) or
2. take a look at [dr. Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=qtooltip&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=de&sclient=psy-ab&q=tooltip%20plugin&oq=tooltip%20plugin&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i30l2j0i10i30j0i30l5.10849.12710.2.12920.14.14.0.0.0.0.317.3155.0j2j10j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.vQkODHRPLnk&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=993a71b657616ada&biw=1600&bih=775)

Personally I've been using **qTip**. There are some nice [examples at qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) which should help you out!

As *@uwe Keim* pointed out, *some* of the *links* above are *outdated*. So here we are with some **current links**

- [**QTip2**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)
- [**SimpleTip**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/#)
- [**30 cool jQuery ToolTip Plugins**](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html) (14.July 2012)
- [**Tipped**](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped)

Comment: Most of these from your first link are outdated, the last time I look. Nearly 3 years old article.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either asp.net way or using jquery

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/12/22/user-friendly-tooltip-using-ajax-hover-menu-extender-control.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/cjdevos/archive/2008/03/29/asp-net-ajax-tooltipextender.aspx

You can use jquery to accomplish this .

http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at the Ajac control toolkit ballon popup:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/BalloonPopup/BalloonPopupExtender.aspx